# Disable all 'Ctrl' key shortcuts in AutoHotkey?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm trying to lock down a kiosk PC and need to disable various 'Ctrl + key' keyboard shortcuts.
I started by disabling them individually using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)...

```
^F4::return
^w::return
^+w::return
^Esc::return
^+Esc::return
;etc...
```

but keep discovering new ones shortcuts (did you know that 'Ctrl + Q' in IE8 displays a tab thumbnail page). So I tried to disable the Ctrl key completely using stuff like:

```
LCtrl::return
RCtrl::return
~Ctrl::return
^::return
```

with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about `Ctrl::return`?

Comment: @Jamie. Tried that

Comment: SharpKeys is your best bet

Answer (score 1):

For the standard shortcuts, refer to [this list](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301583) and setup a hotkey instance to override it. For example, I made an ALT & F4 hotkey, which would normally close the active window, and made it enter some text instead. It works:

```
ALT & F4::
Send foobar ; This line sends keystrokes to the active (foremost) window.
return
```

That only fixes each instance. To disable a key (ALT) by itself use:

ALT::Return

For more on that see [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).

Watch out for other key combinations made possible by installed software/reg edits such as [this](http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=group+policy+disable+shortcuts&d=5039255207348563&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=c8b3e977,4e44b89f) video card instance.

Comment: 'CTRL::Return' doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: It does actually disable the key when pressed by itself. For key combinations such as copy or paste (ctrl+c, ctrl+v) you have to have separate hotkey instances for each (ex ctrl & c::return) See here: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic65275.html

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [Opera Kiosk mode](http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this would be simply to remap the control key to the shift key. That way, control+v becomes shift+v, which is rather less dangerous. It works on my computer.

```
Control::Shift
```